# Maven + GWTTestCase + Test => No source code is available for type nnn (of dependency)

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I'm coding a gwt 2.4 application using Maven. The project is divided into a couple of (Maven) sub-projects. The gwt maven plugin is used for building the project. While the build itself runs fine, I'm running into issues with GwtTests:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/yanosz/app/gwt-app/src/test/java/com/company/gwt-app/ui/ng/gwt/screen/impl/s0A5/GwtTestValidationMeldung.java'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 59: No source code is available for type com.company.commons.gwt.types.LogicalDate; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 61: No source code is available for type com.company.commons.gwt.types.JaNeinType; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 98: No source code is available for type com.company.ui.ng.gwt.screen.layout.messages.MessageAreaDisplay; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 101: No source code is available for type com.company.ui.ng.gwt.screen.support.gwt-appD.ialogYesNoCallback; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 111: No source code is available for type com.company.ui.ng.gwt.infrastructure.scheduler.SchedulerSimple; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 138: No source code is available for type com.company.commons.gwt.ui.UIProperties; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Line 143: No source code is available for type com.company.ui.ng.gwt.screen.support.editor.EditorValidationType; did you forget to inherit a required module?
(....)
[INFO]  [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.company.ui.ng.gwt.screen.impl.s0A5.GwtTestValidationMeldung'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
```

These test can be run in eclipse using *Run As GWT Unit test* - however, I'd like to do so using Maven in order to run 'em on Jenkins.

*Important note*: All missing source-files are part different sub-probjects. They're not included in the project I'm trying to build. They're defined as project dependencies, and mentioned in the compileSourcesArtifacts statement:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <module>${gwt.module}</module>
        <style>${gwt.style}</style>
        <runTarget>GwtApp.html</runTarget>
        <compileSourcesArtifacts>
            <compileSourcesArtifact>com.company.gwt-app:gwt-app-commons</compileSourcesArtifact>
            <compileSourcesArtifact>com.company.gwt-app:gwt-app-ui</compileSourcesArtifact>
        </compileSourcesArtifacts>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Do you why Maven is missing sources in tests while using 'em in compilation (mvn install) is not an issue? How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance,
Greetz yanosz

Edit: The module config for my test is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='gwt-app'>

  <inherits name='com.company.gwt-app.commons.Module' />
  <inherits name='com.company.gwt-app.ui.ng.Module' />
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />

  <entry-point class="com.company.gwt-app.ui.ng.gwt.application.gwt-appEntryPoint" />

  <source path='gwt' />

  <!-- German language, independent of country -->
  <set-property name="locale" value="de" />
  <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="de" />
  <extend-property name="locale" values="en" />

</module>
```

All necessary modules are inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Gwt needs all needed java sources. You has to pack them. See [Multi-Project Setup](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/multiproject.html)

Comment: hmm ... I know gwt needs all java sources - providing 'em is actually what maven does, when doing a gwt build. However, I don't see the reason why they are available during the compilation / installing but not while executing tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the module in your `.gwt.xml`

See: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideModules

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The modules are inherited (see edit of my post I a few secs ago). Btw. did you link to gwt 1.5 on purpose?